# QGIS select by location and use field calculator python

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, select-by-location

I am trying to automate the repetative task of selecting by location and updating a field according to the selection. The issue is that field calculator uses all features instead of the selected. Is there a simple way to do this with qgis python? Here is my code:

```
import processing
moment_all = iface.activeLayer()
moment_all.startEditing()
processing.runalg("qgis:addfieldtoattributestable","filepath.shp","blast",2,2,0,"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp")
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation","filepath.shp","filepath2.shp",['within'],0,0)
processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator","filepath.shp","blast",0,10,3,False,"'b'","filepath.shp")
moment_all.commitChanges()
```

A similar thread I've found is here [QGIS selecting features and using field calculator to update existing field using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225419/qgis-selecting-features-and-using-field-calculator-to-update-existing-field-usin), though I don't think it works for my situation. Would graphical modeler be a better way to do this?

Comment: did you try to set qgis:fieldcalculator input's argument on the activeLayer than the shapefile itself  "filepath.shp" ?

Comment: I just tried using 

    processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator","filepath.shp","blast",0,10,3,False,"'b'","filepath.shp")
moment_all.commitChanges()

still affects the entire column, but I think using the active layer s]instead will resolve this so I will post any updates

Comment: I mean, something like this (not sure of the syntax) : `processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator",moment_all,"blast",0,10,3,False,"'b'","filepath.shp")`

Comment: that seems to work, though I'm not getting any output. If i do these steps manually it works, but when I take my processing history and put it into python as shown nothing really happens..

Comment: with this change ^^ it still affects all rows, however

Comment: Your are trying to set a string inside a float field. that's why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Obviously, there are several misunderstanding. First addfieldtoattributestable might not be necessary cause the fieldcalculator could create a new field if you need (set  the proper parameter to True). Selectbylocation is done on filepath.shp not on the active layer. Then, in qgis:fieldcalculator, your are trying to set a string as a float ().   Finaly your output will be populate with selected features, If there is no selection, all the feature are saved. Be sure your selection is done on the input layer of fieldcalculator. Please send a the simplest code as possible to be more helpfull.

Comment: I set the field to be string in the add attribute function so I don't understand why that would be an issue. Taking out the addattribute function, how do I make sure that ONLY SELECTED FEATURES are calculated? This is beyong simple within the attribute table's field calculator but I dont see an option for it within python.

Comment: would I simply select by location on filepath and then use filepath for fieldcalculator afterwards?

Comment: this addition worked, however it exported only the blast events, erasing the other events. Code below:

processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation","filepath","bufferpath",['within'],0,0)

processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator","filepath","blast",0,10,3,True,"'b'","filepath")

Comment: used correct code below to answer:        

import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation","filepath","buffer_filepath",['within'],0,0)
processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator","filepath","blast",2,2,3,True,"'b'","filepath2")
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation","filepath","buffer_filepath,['disjoint'],0,0)
processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator","filepath","blast",2,2,3,True,"'nb'","filepath3")
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers","filepath2;filepath3","merged_filepath")

Comment: hugo, would you like to answer this question with the above comment ^^^^^? taking away the add attribute field, I calculated 2 layers for 'b' and 'nb' and proceeded to merge them as above ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there are several misunderstanding. First addfieldtoattributestable might not be necessary cause the fieldcalculator could create a new field if you need (set the proper parameter to True). Selectbylocation is done on filepath.shp not on the active layer. Then, in qgis:fieldcalculator, your are trying to set a string as a float (). Finaly your output will be populate with selected features, If there is no selection, all the feature are saved. Be sure your selection is done on the input layer of fieldcalculator. Please send a the simplest code as possible to be more helpfull.

Comment: From this, I got my code to work as seen in the last comments above